# socket connection issue between 2 carriers' network

Tags: java, android, sockets, 3g

I wrote a simple socket program on android, the server side sets up a server socket waiting for incoming connections, the client side just connect to the server by establish a connection with the server's ip address. I'm using Sprint's 3G Nexus S as the server, and ATT'S 4G Samsung galaxy S3 as client. When my client tries to connect, it throws out the exception"No route to destination". But then I switched to my personal WIFI network, it worked perfectly. Can someone help me with this issue? or is there any special requirement in android to use cellular network to set up socket connection? thank you!

My client side is:

```
socket = new Socket(serveripaddress, 8008);
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
```

My server side is:

```
ss = new ServerSocket(8008);
```

update: I just used 2 Sprint cellphones to test my code and it works fine!! This is just a special case in which i have to use phone as server, it is not recommended in general

Comment: Carrier firewalls typically don't allow incoming connections to mobile devices.

Comment: So if I use 2 phones under same carrier, will they block the connection?

Comment: I would expect so but no guarantees.  It can also depend on the APN used.   I wouldn't build any plans around having this work.  Plan on having to put a server in the middle.

Comment: got it, in this special case I have to use a phone as server side, but thanks for your help, Please post your comments as answer and I will pick your answer as best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carrier firewalls typically don't allow incoming connections to mobile devices.  Doing so would leave the mobile devices open to security risks and abuse of their data limits.  It can also depend on the APN used for the connection.