# Establishing socket connection between 2 carriers' network

Tags: android, sockets, network-programming

My question is whether port knocking can help me in the situation stated in this question ([socket connection issue between 2 carriers' network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551409/socket-connection-issue-between-2-carriers-network)) to allow connections between an android server and android client?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the carriers, you *may* be able to. Verizon (in the US) sometimes uses NAT when they run out of IPs. If the Verizon device is a mifi you could wind up with double-NATed routes, but even simple NAT requires the use of UPNP (not generally supported by the routers they use), or an external server to penetrate the network, such as SIP or STUN.